# VS Code open file readonly on breakpoint

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code for many years now and all of a sudden last week all my nodejs projects will open a readonly file when encountering a debugger or breakpoint.

How do I disable this new unwanted functionality that has been forced upon me?

- The path for the original file and readonly file are EXACTLY the same.
- It effect all my individual unrelated nodejs projects. So it is not the launch config or something with the project files.  It must be some global VS Code setting.
- I have no additional addons or modules or whatever they are called installed in VS Code other than what it came with for nodejs.

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132307

tldr: set `enableContentValidation: false` in the launch config

Answer (score 0):

I was using ThreeJs and didn't have a launch.json file. This is how I fixed it.

In the Run & Debug tab on the left click "create a launch.json file"
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMCHS.png)

My launch.json for Chrome

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "enableContentValidation": false,
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "vuejs: chrome",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/main.js"
        }
      }
  ]
}
```

After this you can use the green triangle to attach your visual studio code to your website.

Answer (score 0):

Select in the file that opens read-only and change the encoding to UTF-8 without BOM